# compilation error: no function clause matching in EEx.Compiler.generate_buffer/4

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

This causes an exception, it's an obfuscated version:

```
    <% if @aaa == 1 %>
      <b>Hi</b>
    <% else %>
      <b>Hi2</b>
      <b<%= @var %>
    <% end %>


    <b><%= @var3 %><%= @var4%>

    <% if @var5 == @var6 %>
      <b>Hi3</b>
    <% else %>
      <b>Hi4</b>
    <% end %>
```

The error is:

```
== Compilation error on file web/views/my_model_view.ex ==
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in EEx.Compiler.generate_buffer/4
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You are missing a `do` in your `if`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Elixir syntax for if's is `if do end`.

Ruby/Rails:

```
<% if ... %>
<% end %>
```

Elixir/Phoenix:

```
<% if ... do %>
<% end %>
```